# Nuance of Bound and Bind

Tags: vocabulary

I wanted to know that in this example “**Bound**” stems from “bind” or simply it is the adjective of bound?

“Boys are not bound by stereotypes, they can excel in music and art if they want.”

Answer (score 2):

*Bound* is indeed the past participle of *bind*, but in this use, it is just an adjective:

[Merriam-Webster *bind*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bind)

adjective : placed under legal or moral restraint or obligation :
*obliged, duty-bound*

An example where *bound* would be a verb participle might go like this:
*We found them tied up. They had been bound an hour before.*

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're right that it's the past participle of "bind", but I don't think it's just an adjective since "*by stereotypes*" indicates an agent, which means it's the passive form of the active sentence: "*Stereotypes do not bind boys.*" Or do you think "bound by stereotypes" could be acting as an adjective phrase?

Comment: @gotube I can think of it either way. Is it the stereotypes that are doing the binding, or are they just equivalent to limits? The M-W definition says *obliged* for the adjective definition, but when one is obliged, some stricture or limit is involved, and you could say that that limit is doing the obliging, but *bound* in that sense is still called an adjective.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I interpret the question as, "Is 'bound' an adjective or the past participial verb form in a passive clause?" It can be either, so how to determine which it is? My initial argument was that the "by"-phrase makes it a passive clause, but I've thought about it some more and I found this counter-example: "*The Lego pieces are **sorted by colour***". Here, we have a "by"-phrase, but "colour" is clearly not the agent of "sort", and because it's in the present tense, "sorted" is an adjective describing the pieces, not a verb describing an action. All that to say, you might be right